# How to see "How often do people log in"?

Tags: drupal-views, user, logs

Is there a way to see in civicrm that How often do people log in or to list the users who logged at least once in last 2 months? I have look advanced search but I couldnt find any criteria for this?

Note: I am using CiviCRM 4.7.12

Comment: when you say 'logged in' do you mean they all have a CMS user account - or that some of them are just reacting eg to an email, and they only have a civi record?

Answer (score 1):

**Drupal Views - CiviCRM integration** will let you combine Drupal data (e.g. Username, Role, Last Login) - with CiviCRM data (e.g. Source of Contact). I've trimmed the screenshots to strip out CiviCRM Sort Name, and Email address for privacy reasons.

To figure out who has logged in in the last 2 months - would then simply be a Filter on User: Last Login; If you'd like to filter by Group -> you can do that here too;

If you don't already use Views -> in CiviCRM Core -> Administer -> System Settings -> CMS Database Integration;

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can also use the login tracker module https://www.drupal.org/project/login_tracker

This would allow you to create views that tells you the number of logins per user over time and so on.

Comment: Awesome - thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in CiviCRM to see the login date out of the box. If you are using Drupal as a a CMS you can navigate to yourdomain.org/admin/people and see the time of the last login of a user.

There are also modules that allow you to have more information regaidng logins such as "[Login History](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_history)"

Not sure if/how that is possible with Wordpress or Joomla.

Finally, you can probably find out the time of the last login using SQL queires but this is probably not what youu had in mind.

Comment: Well I am using drupal annd yes I can see the time of the last login. However I would like to see the last login of a specific group(the users who have the emails unsubscribed). For this I have used search builder and I have found all users that receive no email from my page and I have added them into group.However all are done in civicrm.How can I see last login time of these users who are in the group by Drupal?

Note: There are more than 2000 so I can not copy past email addresses to Drupal people search box and check.

Comment: As I said, there is probably no easy way to do that via the CiviCRM UI - sorry. As a workaround you could use CiviGroup Roles Synch (https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/group-roles/) to give all those users a role in Drupal. You would then be able to select those users by role.